# Arduino IDE doesn't find header file

Tags: library

I'm trying to start with the SainSmart 4x20 serial LCD, and copied the library to the Arduino library:

[image]

So `LiquidCrystal_I2C.h` is included. But when I try to compile an example sketch it says

> Arduino: 1.7.0 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"
>
> HelloWorld_i2c.pde:2:31: fatal error: LiquidCrystal_I2C.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> Error compiling.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There is no such thing as Arduino 1.7.0. At the time of writing, the latest Arduino IDE is 1.6.3 http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Comment: It may be the 'Arduino.org' ripoff version. Test the same sketch in the Official Arduino IDE, the one linked by @FedericoFissore

Comment: Please, accept your owm answer to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied the SainSmart library to the IDE's library folder, not noticing that there was already a folder named "LiquidCrystal". Apparently the files added to the existing folder are being ignored.

Renaming the SainSmart library before adding it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info to give a specific answer so I will give some troubleshooting tips:

1. First make sure at the top of your code you have: #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> - with angle brackets
2. You may also need the Wire header file: #include <Wire.h>  - with angle brackets
3. Make sure you Include Serial
4. Make sure there are no extra folders in the library for example there should be a folder called liquidcrystal inside the liquidcrystal folder
5. If all fails copy the code from the header file make a new file in the IDE paste it in there and call it LiquidCrystal_I2C.h

Hope one of those solves your problem.